# subset of data.frame columns to maximize "complete" observations

Tags: r, optimization, mathematical-optimization, subquery

I have a data frame with on the order of 20 numeric columns, each containing significant amounts of NA values. I would like to select a subset of these columns that will give me the most rows containing zero NA values. An exhaustive search would take a lot of computing time--is there a better way to get an approximation?

Here is an example with a smaller data frame (completely arbitrary):

```
set.seed(2)
foo = as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(200), nr = 20))
foo[sapply(foo, function(x) x > abs(x[1]))] = NA
foo = foo[-1, ]

round(foo, 3)

       V1     V2     V3     V4     V5     V6     V7     V8     V9    V10
2   0.185 -1.200 -1.959     NA -1.696  0.261  0.139  0.410 -0.638 -1.262
3      NA  1.590 -0.842 -0.703 -0.533 -0.314     NA -0.807 -0.268  0.392
4  -1.130  1.955     NA  0.158 -1.372 -0.750 -0.431  0.086  0.360 -1.131
5  -0.080  0.005     NA  0.506 -2.208 -0.862 -1.044     NA -1.313  0.544
6   0.132 -2.452     NA -0.820     NA     NA  0.538 -0.654 -0.884     NA
7   0.708  0.477 -0.305 -1.999 -0.653  0.940 -0.670     NA     NA  0.025
8  -0.240 -0.597 -0.091 -0.479 -0.285     NA  0.639  0.550 -2.099  0.515
9      NA  0.792 -0.184  0.084 -0.387 -0.421 -1.724 -0.807 -1.239 -0.654
10 -0.139  0.290 -1.199 -0.895  0.387 -0.351 -1.742 -0.997     NA  0.504
11  0.418  0.739 -0.838 -0.921     NA -1.027  0.690     NA     NA -1.272
12     NA  0.319     NA  0.330     NA -0.251  0.331 -0.169     NA -0.077
13 -0.393  1.076 -0.562 -0.142 -1.184  0.472  0.871     NA  0.057 -1.345
14 -1.040 -0.284     NA  0.435 -1.358     NA -2.016 -0.844  0.324 -0.266
15     NA -0.777 -1.048 -0.054 -1.513  0.564  1.213     NA -0.905     NA
16 -2.311 -0.596 -1.966 -0.907 -1.253  0.456  1.200 -1.343 -0.652  0.701
17  0.879 -1.726 -0.323  1.304     NA     NA  1.032     NA -0.262 -0.443
18  0.036 -0.903     NA  0.772  0.008     NA  0.786  0.464 -0.935 -0.789
19     NA -0.559     NA  1.053 -0.843  0.107     NA  0.268     NA -0.857
20  0.432 -0.247     NA -1.410 -0.601 -0.783 -1.454     NA -1.624 -0.746

dim(na.omit(foo))
[1]  1 10
```

Here is how I've formulated an exhaustive search:

```
best.list = list()
for (i in 5:ncol(foo)) {
    # get best subset for each size
    collist = combn(ncol(foo), i)
    numobs = apply(collist, 2, function(x) nrow(na.omit(foo[, x])))
    cat("for subset size", i, "most complete obs is", max(numobs), "\n")
    best = which(numobs == max(numobs))[1]
    best.list = c(best.list, list(collist[, best]))
}
```

For example, `best.list[[1]]` tells me that if I keep 5 columns I can have 12 complete observations (rows with zero NAs), and that columns 1, 2, 4, 7, and 10 are the ones I should choose.

While this works for very small data frames, it quickly becomes prohibitive with larger ones. Is there a way in R to efficiently estimate the best subset of a given size? The only thing I've been able to find is the `subselect` package, though I can't figure out how to implement its methods for the problem at hand.

Comment: Do you actually need *the best* solution to your problem? If you can live with an approximation, a greedy approach might be helpful (it is at least easy). Choose columns one at a time, in each step picking one that yields the most complete cases together with the columns you already picked.

Comment: ... specifically, you have a discrete optimization problem. Define `X <- (is.na(foo))+0`. Then your problem is equivalent to finding a 0/1 vector `v` with `sum(v)==k` and `sum((X%*%v)[,1]==0)` maximal. It may be that the specific way to solve this in R is the least of your worries, R is not really strong in optimization - you may need to think about the algorithm first. The CRAN optimization task view may be helpful, though I didn't find anything right away: http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html

Comment: An approximation is fine. I don't know a ton about optimization, but I get the gist of greedy algorithms. I'll have a go at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this is the complete solution, but if you want fast results, data.table and a shadow matrix are the most probable ingredients.

```
library(data.table)
df = data.table(foo) # your foo dataframe, converted to data.table

y = sort(df[,lapply(.SD, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))]) # nr of NA in columns, increasing
setcolorder(df, names(y)) # now the columns are ordered - less NA first

df[, idx := rowSums(is.na(df))] # count nr of NA in rows
df = df[order(idx),] # sort by nr of NA in rows
df[, idx := NULL] # idx not needed anymore
# now your data.table is sorted: columns with least NA to the left,  
# rows with with least NA on top

# shadow matrix
x= data.table(abs(!is.na(df)))  # 0 = NA value
y = as.data.table(t(x))
y = y[,lapply(.SD, cumprod)]
y = as.data.table(t(y))
y[,lapply(.SD, sum)] 

# nr of complete cases from column selections:
# V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
# 1: 19 18 16 14 11 10  7  5  2   1
```

Comment: This seems to be a pretty good approximation. I compared it to the exact solution for a few 15-column matrices and it was usually within 1 or 2 of the true answer. Is there any theory on how the error would scale with larger data frames?

Comment: No idea what causes the small difference [other than possible double count of NA in the same rows?]. By the way, the NA sort of the rows [via the idx column] is not required. Comment them out and you have the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Old post, but there's a built in function that does this. I'll bet it's quite efficient:

```
df_noNAs <- df[complete.cases(df[,1:20]),]
```

Comment: I think this function just removes all the rows with NAs, whereas OP is looking for the combination of columns that keep as many columns and rows as possible after NAs are removed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tidyverse solution.

Similar to @Henk solution, the `dfminimiser()` function avoids the process of an exhaustive search by first sorting the columns and rows in decreasing order of missingness.

It returns the data.frame that is most optimised in terms of having the largest number of rows and columns after missing values have been dropped.

I also added a `vars2keep` argument, where you can specify any variables that you definitely want to keep in the final dataset.  These variables are dealt with separately to the rest at the beginning of the function.

Credits to @Onyambu from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78103750/select-the-data-frame-with-maximum-dimensions-from-a-list-of-data-frames) for helping with the line to efficiently select the data.frame with the largest dimensions from the list.

Here is the function:

```r
# Load tidyverse packages:
library(tidyverse)

# Data frame minimiser function:
dfminimiser <- function(df, vars2keep){
  
  # Remove all rows that have NAs in the case definition column:
  df = df %>% 
    drop_na(all_of(vars2keep))
  
  # Create vector of colnames in decreasing order of completeness:
  colnonmiss = colSums(!is.na(df)) %>% 
    sort(decreasing = TRUE) %>% 
    names()
  
  # Sort columns and rows so most complete are at top left:
  df = df %>% 
    select(colnonmiss) %>% 
    arrange(rowSums(is.na(.)))
  
  # Create ordered list of columns to iteratively drop:
  cols2drop = names(df)[!names(df) %in% vars2keep]

  # Remove columns with the most missing one by one and drop NAs:
  dflist = cols2drop %>%
    map(~ df %>% select(1:.x) %>% drop_na())
  
  # Select the data.frame with the biggest dimensions (nrow & ncol):
  dfinal = dflist[[which.max(map_dbl(dflist, ~ prod(dim(.x))))]]
  
  # Return the final data.frame:
  return(dfinal)
  
}
```

Here are the results:

```r
# Apply the function:
foo_final <- dfminimiser(foo, vars2keep = "V1")

# View the results:
> foo_final
            V1           V2         V7         V4         V10
1  -2.31106908 -0.595660499  1.2004947 -0.9071104  0.70056780
2  -1.13037567  1.954651642 -0.4306410  0.1581648 -1.13143826
3  -0.23969802 -0.596558169  0.6388056 -0.4792926  0.51513317
4  -0.13878701  0.289636710 -1.7424301 -0.8954866  0.50364199
5  -0.39269536  1.076164354  0.8710677 -0.1416608 -1.34531938
6  -0.08025176  0.004937777 -1.0442296  0.5062348  0.54414448
7   0.70795473  0.477237303 -0.6695860 -1.9988470  0.02522857
8  -1.03966898 -0.284157720 -2.0162456  0.4348478 -0.26631756
9   0.03580672 -0.902584480  0.7864103  0.7717898 -0.78851997
10  0.43226515 -0.246512567 -1.4538098 -1.4100383 -0.74641901
11  0.41765075  0.738938604  0.6898042 -0.9212757 -1.27211922
12  0.87860458 -1.725979779  1.0320683  1.3035122 -0.44275951
```

I couldn't get all of @Henk's code to work in order to benchmark the two approaches, but this tidyverse solution also seems to be reasonably fast.